# How to execute the quietRun mininet function with a sudo command in call?

Tags: python, sudo, tcpdump, mininet

How could I execute the `quietRun` mininet function with a sudo command in the call? I want to execute a `tcpdump` command in my `python/mininet` program

```
(quietRun('sudo tcpdump -i any -w example.pcap')).
```

#### Error message:

```
sudo: tcpdump -i any -w example.pcap&: command not found
```

Comment: As an alternative, I'm using the command `CLI(net, script=myScript)` in python, where myScript is a string (`myScript="sh tcpdumpCommand.sh"`) that call an external bash script with tcpdump command.